# Как перевести WI-FI адаптер в режим мониторинга на Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

Написал программу для ARP-spoofing на основной машине (Windows 10). Как на этой системе перевести WI-FI адаптер в режим мониторинга? Знаю, что на Linux используется

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Какой аналог этой команды на Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Аналог этой команды это поставить галочку "Разрешить другим пользователям ..." на адеаптере с интернетом и выбрать нужный адаптер в выпадающем списке. Но это не режим мониторинга.

А то что нужно для спуфинга называется Неразборчивый режим.

### На повершеле

Проверь что адаптер сейчас не в нем

```
$(Get-NetAdapter -Name "Подключение по локальной сети").PromiscuousMode
```

Если не включенно, то немного черной магии с IOControl -

```
# Specify the IP Address of the Adapter

$NICIP = "192.168.128.108"



# Do some funky stuff with byte arrays

$byteIn = New-Object Byte[] 4

$byteOut = New-Object Byte[] 4

$byteData = New-Object Byte[] 4096

$byteIn[0] = 1

$byteIn[1-3] = 0

$byteOut[0-3] = 0



# Open an IP Socket

$Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket(
    [Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork,
    [Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Raw, 
    [Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::IP
)

# Include the ip header

$Socket.SetSocketOption("IP", "HeaderIncluded", $true)

# Big packet buffer in bytes

# NOTE: You might need to play with this value if things don't work.
# Try factors of 1024 (for example, 1024, 8192, 24576, 1024000, etc)

$Socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 512000

# Create ip endpoint

$Endpoint = New-Object System.Net.IPEndpoint([Net.IPAddress]$NICIP, 0)

$Socket.Bind($Endpoint)

# Enable promiscuous mode

[void]$Socket.IOControl([Net.Sockets.IOControlCode]::ReceiveAll, $byteIn, $byteOut)
```

Убедись что неразборчивый режим включился

```
$(Get-NetAdapter -Name "Подключение по локальной сети").PromiscuousMode
```

[via](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/9acuq3/enable_promiscuous_mode/)

Но это код лучше перенесите в Вашу программу.

А режим мониторинга это другое ;)